# Images not being displayed

Tags: html, css, image

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="styles/main.css" type="text/css"
    rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>


    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <?php include_once("forall.php");?>
    <?php include_once("template_nav.php"); ?>

    <div id="content"></div>


    <div id="footer">abcd</div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

my css code:

```
*
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}



 body
    {
        font-family: verdana;
        background-image: url(http://local host/Website/imagess/sp.jpg);

    }


#wrapper
{
    width: 1024px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}
#header
{
height:200px;

}

.logo
{
    margin-top: 50px;
    float: left;

height::200px;
    background-image: url(http://local host/Website/imagess/sur99.jpg);


}

#searchbox
{
float:right;
margin-top:100px;

}

#nav{

    clear: both;
height:50px;
    margin-left: 30px;
        background-image: url(http://local host/Website/imagess/s4.jpg);
}
ul#navmenu,ul.submenu1
{
list-style-type:none;
}
ul#navmenu li
{
width:123px;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
float:left;
margin-right:4px;
padding:5px;

}

ul#navmenu a{
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
width:123px;
height:30px;
line-height:30px;

border-radius:5px;
color:white;
font-weight:bold;
margin-top:10px;

}

ul#navmenu .submenu1 a
{
margin-top:3px;
}

ul#navmenu li a:hover
{
background-color:black;
}

ul#navmenu ul.submenu1
{
display:none;
position:absolute;

}

ul#navmenu li:hover .submenu1
{
display:block;
}

.darrow
{
font-size:11pt; 
position:absolute;

top:21px;
right:16px;
color:white;
}


#footer
{
width:1024;
background-color:#696969;

}
```

the include file "forall.php:

```
<div id="header">
<div class="logo">

</div>
<div id="searchbox">
<form id="searching">
<input type="text" name="forsearch">
<input type="button" name="search" 

value="search">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

I have changed my root diectory to "localhost/Website" from localhost/ since My index file and images(in imagess folder) are inside Website folder of wamp/www/Website
when i run my page in WAMP the images are not displayed.
alt text is visible but images are not visible.
plz help

Comment: **This** => `http://local host` <= is **wrong** for one thing, plus are you sure that your images are in fact in `imagess` and not `images`? Keyboards are screwy sometimes. Better make sure that **Kool-Aid** of yours didn't get spilled in there ;-)

Comment: My guess is based on his comment below the code that "imagess" with two "s" is correct. Or, he spilt a couple pitchers of Kool-Aid. :)

Comment: @Ryaminal It was **Coffee** for me once, but I soon fixed that. I drank my keyboard! Now I can talk and spell in any language and be awake all at the same while. ;-)

Comment: Just like **:::ELVIS:::** - the OP has left the building.

Answer (score 3):

In your CSS change

```
background-image: url(http://local host/Website/imagess/sp.jpg);
```

to

```
background-image: url(http://localhost/Website/imagess/sp.jpg);
```

and likewise for all your background images. You have a space in localhost in the url.

Comment: Why would you do this rather than `background-image:url(../images/image-name.jpg);` There's no reason to include an absolute URL, especially as it's localhost! Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: To all co-operating individuals.. My folder name is correct its "imagess" plz dont look for spelling mistakes. i hv done it prior to posting the question. when i use the "<img src> tag in my index.php page then the "alt" text is visible. the div containg the image is visible. But there is broken image icon. Alt text is visible.but image is not displaying.

Comment: when i am inserting image through css using what i have shown in code. i want to insert images into my index page using my css page. but i am unable to do it. my images are not being displayed. while rest of css properties are getting applied perfectly.